# SQLAlchemy - Query Many to Many with association table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to query a many to many with association table without success.
This is my model:

```
favourite_events_association_table = Table('favourite_events', db.Model.metadata,
    db.Column('user_uuid', UUID(as_uuid=True), db.ForeignKey('p_user.uuid'), nullable=False),
    db.Column('event_uuid', UUID(as_uuid=True), db.ForeignKey('event.uuid'), nullable=False),
    extend_existing=True
)

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'p_user'

    uuid = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), unique=True, nullable=False, primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    favourite_events = db.relationship('Event', secondary=favourite_events_association_table)
    ....

class Event(db.Model):
    uuid = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), unique=True, nullable=False, primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    start = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=False), nullable=False)
    ...
```

What I need to do is simply query all event in relation with user x with start > a given date order by start.
In sql is:

```
select e.uuid 
from event e
inner join favourite_events fa on fa.event_uuid = e.uuid
where fa.user_uuid = 'uuid'
and e."start"  > 'date'
order by e."start" desc
```

At the moment i'm doing this iterating over the list:

```
for event in current_user.favourite_events:
    if event.start > now:
        events.append(event)
```

But I obviously don't like this solution since I also have to re-order the list manually.

Any suggestions on how to do this query with sqlalchemy?

In case of this iteration sql alchemy perform a query on every iteration (select * from event where uuid='uuid') or it perform a single query to get all the association (select * from event where uuid in(..)) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out how to make my query using sqlalchemy:

```
Event.query.join(User.favourite_events).filter(User.uuid==current_user.uuid).filter(Event.start >= dt).all()
```

Also after some debugging it seems that sqlalchemy will perform a mysql select at each iteration over a collection.