# Sqlalchemy: how to query tables generated by automap with many-to-many relationship?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using automap on an existing database with multiple tables: A, B, C, D. Among them A and B are linked by an intermediary table A-B that describes their many-to-many relation.

I need to query several columns across all 4 tables based on constraints from individual columns and the A-B relation. Using the `automap_base()` and `prepare()` method I was able to obtain the 4 classes corresponding to the 4 tables.

Currently the query looks like this:

```
rows = session.query(*COLUMNS_WITHIN_TABLES).\
  filter(A.col1 == xxx).\
  filter(B.col2 == xxx).\
  ...
  .all()
```

My question is how to impose the constraint from the A-B intermediary table?

According to the [doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/automap.html#many-to-many-relationships) the A-B table won't be mapped into a standalone class. During debugging I do see class A and B sometimes have a property called "B_collection", "A_collection", but I don't know how to best use them in my query. Plus, when there are more than 1 intermediary table associated with A, seems not all of them show up consistently...

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60874073/sqlalchemy-query-many-to-many-with-association-table), but it was for joining only 2 tables.